# Reassigning function body in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, methods, return

I need to change return function ( **modify()** method) in accordance with the object provided to the constructor. I see two ways to do it:
Via function body reassign:

```
class Modifier<T>{
    lateinit var func: ()->T

    constructor(sendable: Sendable<T>){
        func = {  sendable.send() }
    }
    constructor(modifier: Modifier<T>){
        func = {  modifier.modify() }
    }
    fun modify():T{
        return func()
    }
}
```

and through intermediate variable:

```
class Modifier<T>{
    var result:T

    constructor(sendable: Sendable<T>){
        result = sendable.send()
    }
    constructor(modifier: Modifier<T>){
        result = modifier.modify()
    }
    fun modify():T{
        return result
    }
}
```

But I have some doubts if it is implemented in the correct way. Please give your opinoin how it is effective from the point of view of resource consumption and overall realization. Thanks.

to have the most effective way of switching returning value in conditions of the huge calculation amount (recursion) saving both processing and memory capabilities.

Comment: Looks like the question is: Store the function itself and evaluate it later (possibly multiple times), or evaluate it immediately and just once? Obviously, this only makes sense if the function always yields the same result, and that result is not modifyable. If that's the case, the latter should be more efficient. An in-between way might be to store the function, but cache the value once it has been calculated.

Comment: There is no reason to use `lateinit` for a property that is initialized from all your constructors.

Comment: @tobias_k  Excuse me if the question is not clear. The purpose is to calculate modify() function each time by just linking it to the correct one: sendable.send() or nested modifier.modify(). And to do it without extra interim variables consuming memory and processing e.g. to reassign the function body for this.modify() not engaging  `func: ()->T`  or  `var result:T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first of your two options is the only one that does what you describe in the comments, that you want the value recalculated every time `modify()` is called. You have to store the function reference to be able to call it repeatedly. The function reference will capture a reference to your Sendable or Modifier instance, so it will stay in memory even if not referenced elsewhere outside this class.

(By the way, `lateinit` is unnecessary for a property that is initialized in every constructor or in an `init` block.)

You can shorten your syntax as follows. It seems a little weird to define a lambda to do nothing but call a single function so this syntax is a little more idiomatic, although there isn't a firm convention on this. The compiler will treat it the same.

```
class Modifier<T>{
    var func: ()->T

    constructor(sendable: Sendable<T>){
        func = sendable::send
    }
    constructor(modifier: Modifier<T>){
        func = modifier::modify
    }
    fun modify():T{
        return func()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one assigns to the `func` a function. So, each time you would call `modify()` the result will be recalculated:

```
call Modifier.modify()
  call Modifier.result()
    calculate assigned fun (potentially long call)
  return result
return result
```

The second one, however, caches the result (the result is assigned to the result when the object is constructed).

```
call Modifier.modify()
  // no more calculation, result is already here, just return it
return Modifier.result
```

So it depends on what you need - to calculate the result once, or recalculate it each time.